# How to increase speed and flow of movement on Dolphin Emulator

Tags: nintendo-wii, emulation, performance, super-smash-bros-brawl, dolphin-emulator

I am trying to play Super Smash Bros Brawl on the Dolphin Emulator but the speed of the game is incredibly slow.

What can I do to prevent this problem, so that I get faster character animations and movement?

Comment: Slow emulation usually happens on lower end PCs. Please add some more info to your question - specify what are the specs of your PC, what have you tried so far, etc.

Answer (score 14):

Here are a few things you can do, to improve the speed on Dolphin: (Source: [Dolphin Wiki Performance Guide](http://wiki.dolphin-emu.org/index.php?title=Performance_guide))

## Config

- General

  - ***Enable Dual Core*** checked. Usually enabled by default, improves performance on multi-core systems.
  - *Enable Idle Skipping* checked. Usually enabled by default.
  - ***JIT Recompiler*** (enabled by default) or ***JITIL experimental recompiler***.
- Audio

  - *DSP HLE emulation*
  - *DSP on Dedicated Thread* checked. Not recommended, according to the Devs.

## Graphics

- General

  - Backend

    - ***Direct3D9*** (Windows only; [deprecated as of Dolphin 4.0](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2013/10/12/d3d9-why-its-not-part-dolphins-future/))
    - ***OpenGL*** (as of Dolphin 4.0; *"fastest Dolphin video backend on NVIDIA cards"*, see: [*OpenGL video backend rewrite*](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2013/09/22/dolphin-40-release-announcement/))
  - Display

    - *V-Sync* unchecked
- Enhancements

  - ***Internal Resolution*** 1x Native
  - ***Anti-Aliasing*** None
  - *Anisotropic Filtering* 1x
  - *Per-Pixel Lighting* unchecked
- Hacks

  - ***Skip EFB Access from CPU*** unchecked
  - *Ignore Format Changes* checked
  - *EFB Copies* Texture
  - *Texture Cache* Fast
  - *External Frame Buffer* -> *Disable* checked
  - *OpenMP Texture Decoder* checked

The bold options may greatly improve performance. Keep in mind, though, that some games require some options to be enabled/disabled, even if this would reduce performance. For example: *Skip EFB Access from CPU* is an option that greatly reduces emulation speed, but is needed for *Super Mario Galaxy*.

If messing around with these options do not help achieving a fast enough speed, you may always try this:

***Emulation*** -> ***Frame Skipping*** increase the value

This improves the emulation speed, but also results in laggy animations (as a result of skipping frames). The higher the value, the faster the emulation and the laggier the animations will be.
Setting it to 1 or 2 is usually good enough.

If all else fail: Get a faster CPU.
According to the Devs, Dolphin does not benefit from more than 2 cores. Also: More GHz == better (Intel and AMD CPUs do not perform the same at the same clock speed, though, so you might want to keep that in mind before purchase).

Comment: I would argue that you're slightly off-track here. For something like an emulator, I've learned from personal experience that better GPUs (graphics processing units) are much more important than better CPUs.

Comment: @Turtleweezard I have an i7 3770k and a GTX 680. *Monster Hunter Tri* runs at 30 FPS and my GPU usage remains between 20% and 50% while my CPU is constantly at 25% (100% for 2 cores, which is the maximum Dolphin can use), so obviously my CPU is bottlenecking my GPU, and they're both high end. Also, *Super Mario Galaxy* is known to be one of the most CPU intensive games to emulate, as it requires a very CPU intensive feature. It is said, that you can't expect *Galaxy* to run at full speed, unless you OC your CPU to over 4GHz; 5GHz for AMD CPUs.

Comment: @Turtleweezard To back up my claim that a faster CPU is more important than a faster GPU, I've waded through the Dolphin forums and found [this post](http://forums.dolphin-emu.org/Thread-performance-problems?highlight=hardware), where a user says `I have a 2010 Macbook Pro 15 inch OS x 10.8. With an i7-620m @ 2.66 and 3.33 Turbo boost. Also I have an Nvidia GeForce 330m with video memory 512mb and 8gb of DDR3 ram` and asks if he can play the Metroid series. The answer is `your CPU is a bit weak for Metroid Prime 1/2/3` no mention of the (low end) GPU being too slow.

Comment: I stand corrected then.

Comment: *"Intel and AMD CPUs do not perform the same at the same clock speed"* - Even among processors from the same company, the difference in speed between two different models can be pretty drastic.  Try comparing a Core 2 Duo to an i7; even at the same clock-rate and number of cores, the i7 will greatly outperform the Core 2 Duo.

Comment: Note: `Direct3D9` shows up as *deprecated* in Dolphin 4.0.

Comment: @DenilsonSá Thanks, I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @DenilsonSá [More on that.](https://dolphin-emu.org/blog/2013/10/12/d3d9-why-its-not-part-dolphins-future/)